# Is there a better way

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using a statefull service to get questions. If questions exist in service local state, then it return them otherwise it requests them from an http call to api and store them.

This service method return an Observable of Question[]. My container store the observable inside a variable and pass it to presentational components using async pipe.

I succeeded in writing the service function but I'm not sure it is the best way of doing it.

Can you please tell me if there is a better or a more elegant way of doing ?

Here is the code :

question.api.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Question } from './models/question.model';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionApi {
  static readonly BASE_PATH = 'http://myapi.io';

  private _questionsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Question[]>(null);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  public getQuestions(): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this._questionsSource.asObservable().pipe(
      switchMap(val => val ?
        this._questionsSource.asObservable() :
        this.http.get<Question[]>(`${QuestionApi.BASE_PATH}/question`).pipe(
          map(data => this._questionsSource.next(data))
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

questions-page.component.ts

```
@Component()
export class QuestionsPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public questions$: Observable<Question[]>;

  constructor(
    private _api: QuestionApi
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.questions$ = this._api.getQuestions();
  }
```

questions-page.component

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(questions$ | async) as questions; else loadingQuestions">
  <app-questions [questions]="questions"></app-questions>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loadingQuestions>
  <p class="text-center">Loading questions</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Your BehaviorSubject has no initial value. This code should not be able to compile.

Comment: That's right, I updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First, create a QuestionsService to do your http calls.

Second, no need to create a BehaviorSubject, just return your Observables :

```
...
questions = undefined;
public getQuestions(): Observable<Question[]> {
 return questions ? Observable.of(questions) :      
                    this._questionsService.getQuestions()
                    .pipe(tap(questions => this.questions = questions));
}
...
```

If you are looking for a more elegant way to do that, you are may be looking for [@ngrx/store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/store).

Comment: I agree with ngrx/store but it's another step. The solution you suggested is not working. That's what I did first. Once your service function is called and it returned the http.get observable the component will store it and will not call the service function again. when resubscribed when the child component is hidden/shown (using async pipe) it will make an api call again despite the data is stored in the service.

Comment: You are trying to make a hot observable out of your cold observable, you can use the rxjs share operator. I made a simple example of how it works (https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49030306?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). This way, you are going to be able to subscribe multiple times to the same Observable, and all your observers gonna have the same value at the same time.